# Although the missed approach point in the profile view is 1.1 DME-400 feet, the GS out reference altitude is given as 410 feet in 1.0 DME. HOW?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, altitude, jeppesen, missed-approach, dme

Although the missed approach point in the profile view is 1.1 DME-400 feet, the GS out reference altitude is given as 410 feet in 1.0 DME. HOW?!

[image]

Based on GS out reference altitudes, we are expected to be at 410 feet at 1.0 DME. But if we look at the profile view, we see that the missed approach point corresponds to 400 feet at 1.1 DME. How is this possible?

If this is a mistake, I cannot understand how it was overlooked. But if there's a logical explanation, I'd like to know. Also, if there is an error, I would like to know which information is an error and which information is correct. I know the references given are approximate and I also know that the calculations don't quite match (slant range, shape of the earth, rounding the DME value to 1 decimal place, etc.). But there is a big mistake here.

I'm also sharing the entire Jeppesen chart page for clarity:
[image]
LTAF Adana International Airport Jeppesen chart page 21-1.

Answer (score -1):

The descent angle is different: ILS 3°, LOC 3,08°.
So the altitudes will be different at the same DME distances.

Comment: What you said is correct, but the "missed approach point" is the point given according to the LOC descent angle (3.08 degrees) and in the profile view given as 400 feet at 1.1 DME. In addition, the IADA DME-Altitude chart given above also represents the LOC descent angle approach since it is GS out and says that we should be at 410 feet at 1.0 DME. So both things represent the LOC descent angle, while one gives 1.1 DME-400' and the other 1 DME-410'. @Jon