# Why are there two Decision Altitudes at LTBR Bursa Yenişehir?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, jeppesen, missed-approach

[image]

Hello,

As you can see, at the missed approach point, the chart gives 984 feet. On the other hand, The Decision altitude given as 959 feet. What is the reason ? Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Although the missed approach point in the profile view is 1.1 DME-400 feet, the GS out reference altitude is given as 410 feet in 1.0 DME. HOW?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/97710/although-the-missed-approach-point-in-the-profile-view-is-1-1-dme-400-feet-the)

Answer (score 4):

The glideslope altitude at the LOC MAP is 984. That’s not the DA.

Comment: Isn't the LOC MDA 1750? What's the point of including this extra figure?

Comment: @Ben The MDA is 1750, but if you were flying the ILS (and could execute the 5.4% climb out) then the altitude serves as a check just prior to hitting the DA (959). Likewise, if you were leveling at 1750 on the LOC it would provide a good indication for how much lower the normal 3 degree glidepath is to the runway at the MAP (should you get the runway in sight).

Comment: If you look at the history in the U.S. of "middle marker beacons" - **MM** (FAA Instrument Flying Handbook, AIM, etc.) you would see that their primary purpose was to alert the pilot, flying an ILS, that he/she was at the approximate decision height point (of course now the point would be the Decision Altitude).  When I received my Instrument Rating in 1973 I can't remember ever flying an ILS without an MM. They were used as a cross check that you were near or over the DA/MAP.  My guess is that since the LOC MAP is already marked (.7 from IYEN), this is serving the same purpose as MM used to.